# SQL constraint to check another table column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

So essentially I have the following problem to implement as part of an oracle sql database:

table1(attr1, attr2)

table2(attr3, table1_attr1)

**Constraint: a table2 tuple can only have some table1_attr1 for which tuple in table1 attr2 is not null.**

I have tried the following (along with other commented out possibilities), but it obviously doesn't work because attr2 is not a unique value:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  attr1                VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
  attr2             VARCHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY(attr1)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  attr3                  INTEGER       NOT NULL,
  table1_attr1       VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
  table1_attr2         VARCHAR(50),  --REFERENCES table1(attr2),

  FOREIGN KEY (table1_attr1, table1_attr2) REFERENCES table1(attr1, attr2),
    CONSTRAINT const_table1 CHECK(table1_attr2 IS NOT NULL),

  PRIMARY KEY(attr3)
);
```

I need some help, since making attr2 unique is not an option.
I have read about making a function somewhere, but I'm not very familiar with them. Will try it if they are the only choice.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer by myself. It will sound silly, but I do hope it helps anyone else out there struggling with this case.

By adding:

> UNIQUE (attr1, attr2)

inside `table1` we are creating a unique key, but since the primary is just attr1, there is no way that there would be duplicates of the same tuple with different `attr2`s.

Point being, now the combination of these two is a unique key, without affecting the rest of the database. And so the check constraint in `table2` can be done without trouble at all.